# Updating of links before copying values over to another file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that contains many links to other files.

What I'm trying to achieve is to open that file and to copy some cells (many of which contain the aforementioned links) to another worksheet. However, it seems as though the links are not updating BEFORE the copying and pasting is done; the links only update AFTER the macro has been completed running. Is there a way to force the source file to update its links before the subsequent code copies from it?

The code looks like this:

```
Workbooks.Open "sourcefile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=1
Workbooks("sourcefile.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
Workbooks("destfile.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try waiting after the workbook.open?

> ```
> Do
>    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
> DoEvents
> Loop
> ```

Comment: yep tried this too, but doesn't work unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
Do
   ThisWorkbook.Activate
   ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources, 
      Type:=xlExcelLinks
   DoEvents
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Loop
```